# Kentico's Continuous Integration is very slow

Tags: continuous-integration, kentico

My Continuous Integration is running ver very slow. 
After launch with -r "ContinuousIntegration.exe -r" it hangs after "Restoring objects…" and before "Optimizing file repository…". It can last within that state even for an hour. After all everything is imported well...

With a profiler I've found that most time is consumed by CMS.DataEngine.TranslationHelper

Anyone has some ideas what is wrong ? [Click here to see the screenshot of profiler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndhsL.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a lot of custom objects or data within those out of the box or custom objects with relationships when you are doing a `-r` it can take a long time to update your local instance.  Simply put, it's rebuilding the whole database with the structure in the CI files.  Also, the documentation states:

*To ensure that the restore process works correctly, you need to stop your Kentico application before running the restore process. Otherwise you may encounter the following problems:*

- *Deadlocks or data inconsistencies if the system attempts to write to the CIRepository folder while data is being restored from the files*
- *Outdated content in the application's cache if you restore without restarting (can cause inconsistencies in the Kentico administration interface or the website's content)*

So be sure to stop your instance when restoring to help with the performance.